# How a program in 16 bit system can access integers more than 65535 but not address

Tags: c++, c, memory, operating-system, programming-languages

A 16 bit system can only access RAM upto 64kbytes (normally). There is a concept of memory addresses that 16 bit system can access 2^16 numbers thus in unsigned integers it can only access 2^16 = 65536 INTEGERS (0 to 65535). Thus 16 bit sytem can only use addresses upto 64kbytes(after conclusion of small calculation). now the main que. Is that when we define an integer to be 'long int' than how can it access integers more than 65535?

Comment: @OP How about those languages that support arbitrary length integers?  Do they run on CPU's with arbitrary length integers?

Comment: "N bit system" typically refers to bit size of the processor's native integer type.  The range of memory space is an _indepenet_ factor.  Often the same, but can be larger or smaller.  Extreme theoretical example 1-bit [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) with infinite memory.

Comment: @chux Reinstate Monica-sorry sir but i m a begginer so can you pls define this more or guide me because i m understanding your reply a little bit.

Comment: There are *many* ways to do arithmetic and other stuff on numbers larger than what a machine natively handles. See the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library for an example. Just because numbers are larger than a machine register doesn't mean we can't work with them - values can be put in memory or even swap/disk storage and calculations can be done in pieces - slow, yes, but functional.

Comment: @AsifBhai "in previous days that a 16 bit system can only access RAM upto 64kbytes." --> What is the source of this idea?

Comment: This i studied in an youtube video tutorial of C language

Comment: Sorry this is my fault

Comment: Previous days mean in my previous days not previous computers

Comment: I m editing question a little bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of misconceptions in this post:

> I came to know in previous days that a 16 bit system can only access RAM upto 64kbytes

This is factually wrong, the 8086 has a external address bus of 20 bits, so it can access 1,048,576 bytes (~1MB). You can read more about the 8086 architecture here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086.

> Is that when we define an integer to be 'long int' than how can it access integers more than 65535?

Are you asking about register size? In that case the answer is easy: it doesn't. It can access the first 16 bits, and then it can access the other 16 bits, and whatever the application does with those 2 16 bit values is up to it (and the framework used, like the C runtime).

As to how you can access the full address space of 20 bits with just 16bit integers, the answer is address segmenting. You have a second register (CS, DS, SS, and ES on 8086) that stores the high part of the address, and the CPU "stitches" them together to send to the memory controller.

Comment: Ok i can understand what you tell about 8080 but still i m confused that if  like a big integer it can access first 16 digits and than second 16 digits,why it cannot access address in two parts.

Comment: The external address bus is a *bus*, it doesn't work with "first part" or "second part" or whatever. The state of every single one of the 20 pins have to have the correct value during the memory controller's read cycle, or it fails.

Comment: @blindy-is it not possible to access big addresses in two cycles of memory bus

Comment: Nope. Again, read the 8086 specification for details if you want, but this is really basic memory access that's used for any micro-processor pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

Computers can perform arithmetic on values larger than a machine word in much the same way as humans can perform arithmetic on values larger than a digit: by splitting operations into multiple parts, and keeping track of "carries" that would move data between them.

On the 8086, for example, if AX holds the bottom half of a 32-bit number and DX holds the top half, the sequence:

```
    ADD AX,[someValue]
    ADC DX,[someValue+2]
```

will add to DX::AX the 32-bit value whose lower half is at address [someValue] and whose upper half is at [someValue+2].  The ADD instruction will update a "carry" flag indicating whether there was a carry out from the addition, and the ADC instruction will add an extra 1 if the carry flag was set.

Some processors don't have a carry flag, but have an instruction that will compare two registers, and set a third register to 1 if the first was greater than the second, and 0 otherwise.  On those processors, if one wants to add R1::R0 to R3::R2 and place the result in R5::R4, one can use the sequence:

```
Add R0 to R2 and store the result in R4
Set R5 to 1 if R4 is less than R0 (will happen if there was a carry), and 0 otherwise
Add R1 to R5, storing the result in R5
Add R3 to R5, storing the result in R5
```

Four times as slow as a normal single-word addition, but still at least somewhat practical.  Note that while the carry-flag approach is easily extensible to operate on numbers of any size, extending this approach beyond two words is much harder.